# Двойное срабатывание JS кода

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, form

Есть форма

```
<form id="subscribe">
 <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="blabla">
 <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="blabla@blabla.ru">
 <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Test text">
 <input type="text" size="60" name="E-Mail" placeholder="Введите e-mail" required>
 <button>Подписаться</button>
</form>
```

Есть JS, использующий Jquery для сабмита

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#subscribe").submit(function() {
        var th = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "script.php",
            data: th.serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            alert("Спасибо!");
            setTimeout(function() {
                th.trigger("reset");
            }, 1000);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

При нажатии скрипт срабатывает, но почему-то выдает 2 алерта и отправляет 2 письма. Больше подключений этого скрипта или формы с подобным id нет.
Подскажите в чем может быть проблема и почему код может срабатывать 2 раза?

Comment: поставьте брейкпойнт на строчку `var th = $(this);` и изучите call-stack в обоих случаях. Все же похоже, что скрипт включен в страницу два раза, так как в самом скрипте все правильно.

Comment: Думаю, что происходит следующее. Вызывается обработчик `submit` при отправке формы, а нём Вы вызываете функцию `$.ajax()` для отправки формы. Чтобы этого не происходило, нужно изменить код формы таким образом, чтобы вместо `submit` обрабатывать событие `onclick` для кнопки. То есть вместо `<button>` использовать тег `<input type="button">`.

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics
Спасибо за наводки, проблема решилась. Как решил - описал ниже. Вот только одна проблема - не могу понять почему так происходило, когда форма и подгрузка скрипта были в одном div-блоке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется проблема найдена. Изначально скрипт был вставлен в страницу сразу после формы, обернутой в div. Перенес его под закрытие тега body - срабатывать начал 1 раз.
Причина такого странного поведения, к сожалению, мне не понятна.

Comment: В каком месте страницы находится таг script, который грузит jquery?

Comment: Да, и это называется не "проблема найдена", а "проблема спрятана".

Comment: @Igor, jquery подгружается в хедере, данный скрипт, который я описал выше находился сразу за </form> в пределах одного div-блока

Comment: желательно было бы получить минимальный пример кода страницы, воспроизводящий описаное поведение

Comment: @Igor,
    <div>
        <form id="subscribe">
         <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="blabla">
         <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="blabla@blabla.ru">
         <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Test text">
         <input type="text" size="60" name="E-Mail" placeholder="Введите e-mail" required>
         <button>Подписаться</button>
    </form>
    <script src="blabla.js"></script>
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="subscribe">
 <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="blabla">
 <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="blabla@blabla.ru">
 <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Test text">
 <input type="text" size="60" name="E-Mail" placeholder="Введите e-mail" required>
 <button type="button" class="submit">Подписаться</button>
</form>
```

По умолчанию у `<button>` type="submit" и тем самым вы пинаете два раза один и тот же запрос...

```
$(function() {
    $(".submit").on('click', function() {
        var th = $('#subscribe');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "script.php",
            data: th.serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            alert("Спасибо!");
            setTimeout(function() {
                th.trigger("reset");
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Вот так не должно отправлять 2 запроса

Comment: А зачем Вам тогда `return false;`?

Comment: На всякий случай, можно и убрать.

Comment: почитайте https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming